# Bad max value in column in awk

Tags: awk, max

i have this data :

```
Values  
10  
20  
30  
40  
50  
12  
15  
18
```

I want to have the max of the column, skipping the first line so i tried :

```
awk 'NR>1 || a<$1{a=$1}  END{print a}' file.txt
```

But it returns `18` when I expected `50`. Where is my mistake ?

P.S :

```
awk ' a<$1{a=$1}  END{print a}' file.txt
```

It returns `Values` which is not good either

Comment: Thanks it works now, last question, why when i try `awk 'NR>1 && a>$1{a=$1}  END{print a}' file.txt` i have an empty result ?

Comment: It should be `a<$1`. Since file.txt has no values less the default zero, `a` is empty.

Comment: Ok i wanna just try the min value, so i must redefine the default zero for the min ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the minimum values from a single column file with a header:

```
awk 'NR > 1 && min=="" || min > $1 { min = $1 } END { print min }' file.txt
```

Get the maximum values from a single column file with a header:

```
awk 'NR > 1 && max < $1 { max = $1 } END { print max }' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do get the maximum value by

```
awk '{if ($1 >= a) a=$1} END {print a }' file.txt
```

And for finding the minimum value

```
awk '{if ($1 <= a) a=$1} END {print a }' file.txt
```